# Match if element of array is a partial match to a string?

Tags: arrays, perl

I am aware of

```
if ( grep(/^$pattern$/, @array) ) {...}
```

which will return true if the entire string is found in an element of the array.
However im trying to figure out how to return true if one of the elements in the array is a partial match to the end of the string.

For example:

```
my @array = (".com", ".net", ".org");
my $domain = "www.example.com";   #<--Returns True
   $domain = "www.example.gov";   #<--Returns False
   $domain = "www.computer.gov";  #<--Returns False, .com not at end
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this without creating a `foreach()` and using a `m//` match against each element?

Comment: Do you mean `grep /\.(?:com|net|org)$/, @domains;`?

Comment: [`s/PERL/Perl/g`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1#What's-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22?)

Comment: Leave the initial `^` off to match anchored only at the end.

Comment: @JimGarrison
But wouldn't that try to match "example.com" inside of ".com"? There is no "example.com" inside of ".com" but there is a ".com" inside of "example.com". Or am i misunderstanding?

Comment: Sorry @TLP i wasn't trying to be snarky. I made the assumption that since i was just talking and didn't block it as code like `$string` it would be obvious it was being used conceptually. Now i know better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
my @array = (".com", ".net", ".org");
my $pattern = join "|", map quotemeta, @array;

if ($domain =~ /(?:$pattern)$/)    # $ matches end of string
```

Comment: `join '|', map quotemeta, @array`.

Comment: You still need `/(?:$pattern)$/`, otherwise the $ will be part of the last alternative only.

Comment: And here I was thinking I could just wing it and write up a simple answer.

Comment: I tried it out using the `($domain =~ /(?:$pattern)$/)` and confirm it works correctly to match only the end. Thank you @TLP.

Comment: @Private_Citizen I think this one was a group effort tbh. :)

Comment: Matches `foo.com<LineFeed>` too

Answer (score 3):

Can use `any` from [List::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/List::Util#any)

```
if ( any { $re = quotemeta; $string =~ /$re$/ } @ary )  { ... }
```

The `$` matches the end of the string so the above matches any `$string` for which `$re` pattern is at its end (regardless of what comes before in that string).
The [quotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta) escapes all "*ASCII non-word characters*", so (also) things that have a special meaning inside a regex. In this case it turns that `.` (a pattern matching any character) into `\.`, a literal dot.

The `quotemeta` has a `\Q ... \E` form that can be used inside a regex, for

```
if ( any { $string =~ /\Q$_\E$/ } @ary )  { ... }
```

But careful with it to not escape other parts of a potentially more complex pattern.